# To prove that $f(x)\ge {{1}\over {2}}(x-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

**Question :**

Let $f\gt 0$ be  continuous on $[1,\infty )$ . Let $$g(x)= \int_1^x f(t)dt\le [f(x)]^2 . \tag1$$
Prove that $$f(x)\ge {{1}\over {2}} (x-1)$$

**My Thoughts :**

Seeing  the  *square*  on  the r.h.s  of  the  given  condition  and  the  ${{1}\over {2}}$  on  the  r.h.s  on  the  desired  result, I  had a  hunch  that  may  be  differentiating  both  sides  will  work.

$$g(x)=\int_1^x f(t)dt=\int_0^xf(t)dt-\int_0^1f(t)dt$$
So  differentiating  both  sides  of  equation $(1)$  **:** 
$$2\cdot f(x)\cdot f'(x) \ge g'(x) =f(x)
$$ 
or, $$2\cdot f(x)\cdot f'(x)\ge f(x)$$
or, $$f(x)[2\cdot f'(x)-1]\ge 0$$

As  $f\gt 0$  is  given , from  the  above , we  get , $$f'(x)\ge {{1}\over {2}}$$

Integrating  from $1$  to $x$  both  sides  $$f(x)-f(1) \ge {{1}\over {2}} (x-1)$$

Now  I  think  after  this  I  have  to  show  $f(1)=0$  and  the  proof  is  done . But I  could  not  prove  this  one  thing.

Comment: Note that in general differentiating an inequality does not give a valid inequality (e.g. $\sin{x} \leqslant 1$, but $\cos{x} $ is not less than zero).

Comment: And moreover $f$ need not be differentiable at all.

Comment: Use $g\leq\big(g^{\prime}\big){2}$, which yields by seperation of variables that $1\leq\frac{g^{\prime}}{\sqrt{g}}$. Integrate this over $[1,x]$. This will probably lead you to the result after combining with **(1)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x) = g'(x)$, and $g(x)>0$ for $x>1$ since $f>0$, so $g(x)\le[f(x)]^2 \implies \frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}\ge 1$ for $x>1$. Integrating from $1$ to $x$ gives
$$ 2\left(\sqrt{g(x)} - \sqrt{g(1)}\right)\ge x-1 \implies \frac{1}{2}(x-1)\le\sqrt{g(x)}\le f(x). $$